# How can i exhibit coercion (a type of ad hoc polymorphism behaviour) in java?

Tags: java, polymorphism

Since java is an object orientated language it should exhibit polymorphism. Below is my definitions of a type of polymorphism; ad-hoc polymorphism, and a subtype of that; coercion.

Ad-hoc polymorphism is obtained when a function works, or appears to work, on several different types (which may not exhibit a common structure) and may behave in unrelated ways for each type. There are two types of ad-hoc polymorphism, coercion and overloading.

Coercion is a semantic operation that avoids a type error.  The compiler converts one type into another in order to match an argument type in a function call to the parameter type in the function definition.  The function definition only works on one type. Compilers implement coercion at compile time.

I have this example working in C++

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 void display(int a) const
 {
     cout << "One argument (" << a
          << ')' << endl;
 }

 int main( )
 {
     display(10); // returns "One argument (10)"
     display(12.6); // narrowing // returns "One argument (12)"
 }
```

Im trying to implement the same program in java without success.

```
public static void display (int i)
{
  System.out.println("One argument (" + i + ")");
}

public static void main (String[] args)
{
  display(10); // One argument (10)
  display(12.6); // Narrowing (a type of coercion) takes place. One argument (12)
}
```

but I am receiving the error.

```
The method display is not applicable for the arguments(double).
```

Do you know how to convert successfully. Please be aware that I really wish to use coercion technique where the compiler fixes the types automatically. So i casting to int with (int) 12.6 is not an option for me.

If you have another coercion example which exhibits narrowing, I would be grateful if you shared it with me :)

Regards.

Comment: I think you could simplify this to just the final code snippet, the error message, and the actual question (i.e. "how can I do this without an explicit cast?").  All the stuff about ad-hoc polymorphism, etc. is just a distraction...

Comment: The only time I can think of where this might happen is when dealing with autounboxing. ie: your generic java collection is actually of type Integer, but you can assign an Integer to an int.

Comment: Take a look at my edit, because there's something funny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java doesn't allow narrowing coercion but just widening coercion.

So there are allowed:

```
float foo(float f) { return f*f; }

int i = 10;
float f = foo(i);
float f2 = i;
```

But not when you are going to lose precision.

EDIT: Actually since a float in java is a standard 4 byte IEEE754 you do actually lose precision but it is allowed in any case, this shows this behavior:

```
int d = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
float f = d;
System.out.println(String.format("%d != %12.0f", d, f));
```

You'll have:

```
2147483647 != 2147483648
```

So the answer is a little bit more fuzzy than it appears.

Comment: Re: your edit.  The JLS explicitly explains this: "A widening primitive conversion does not lose information about the overall magnitude of a numeric value." ... "A widening conversion of an int or a long value to float, or of a long value to double, may result in loss of precision".

Answer (score 3):

Nice reference [here:](http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/FAQ-JAVA-Differences-Between-JAVA-And-C-CPP) "In Java, if coercion will result in a loss of data, you must always explicitly cast the data element to the new type."

Quick answer: you can't. Sorry.

On the other hand, it's really, really hard to write Java code that can't be unpicked by someone who knows what they're doing.

Comment: excellent reference! just to confirm that widening as opposed to narrowing is allowed?

Comment: Yes, it is. This sentence is only here to make it longer than SO's minimum (sigh).

Answer (score 2):

Put simply, Java does not allow implicit narrowing conversions.  So even the following will not compile:

```
double d = 12.6;
float f = d;
```

Note that "width" (as in "widening" and "narrowing" is really about range, not precision).

From the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2):

> **Assignment Conversion**
>
> Assignment conversion occurs when the value of an expression is
>   assigned to a variable: the type of the expression must be converted
>   to the type of the variable.
>
> Assignment contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> - an identity conversion
> - a widening primitive conversion
> - a widening reference conversion
> - a boxing conversion optionally followed by a widening reference conversion
> - an unboxing conversion optionally followed by a widening primitive conversion.

and elsewhere in that chapter:

> Method invocation conversion ... performs the same conversions that assignment conversion does.

You will notice that "narrowing primitive conversion" is not in that list.